# Is there a reputation cap per day, or is it a bug?

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I posted a few answers yesterday on Math.SE, and for some reason [one of them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809965/find-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-sqrtn-frac2nn-using-riemann/1809974#1809974) picked up steam: it currently has been upvoted 22 times, which is... quite pleasing, even if it sounds vain.

Now, what baffles me is that out of these 22 upvotes, I got 91+31=122 reputation in total, which upvotes being somehow capped both yesterday and today:

[image]

As far as I can tell, there is no downvote on that question, and I don't understand what is going on. Is it normal?

(weirdly, this seems to have happened as well on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809882/decreasing-function-that-behaves-like-1-x2-for-small-x-and-like-e-x-fo/1809885#1809885) yesterday, where apparently I got +60 in total (all taken into account) while receiving 7 upvotes.)

*(I know it sounds very petty, but I can't help being baffled...)*

Comment: Yes, there is a reputation cap. You can receive at most 200 rep per day from upvotes. Bounties and accepts are exempt from the cap.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/daily-reputation-limit/info) for some basic info. (And also some other posts with this tag.)

Comment: Oh, thanks. "RTFM," I reckon :) (Should I delete my question, or can one of you post an answer that I can accept?)

Comment: Re: "for some reason". The reason might have been that the question feature in the network-wide [hot questions list](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/hot-questions-list/info) for some time.

Comment: @ClementC. You should keep this question up - it could be a useful signpost for other people with the same question.

Comment: @MiloBrandt OK.